# Count number of characters in the given string and print

Tags: java, string

I am trying to find the number of characters in a String and print it.

For example:

Input:

```
aaaaaggff
```

Output: (Not successful)

```
aaaaa5gg2ff2
```

Code:

```java
      for (int h = 0; h < fe - 1; h++) {
         if (s4[h] == s4[h + 1]) {
            ++c;
            sw[h] = s4[h];
         }
         else {
            String st = Character.toString(s4[h]);
            st = st + "" + c;
            if (sw[h] == ' ') {
               sw[h] = st.charAt(0);
               sw[h + 1] = st.charAt(1);
               c = 1;
               st = "";
            }
            else {
               int v = h * 2 - 1;
               sw[v] = st.charAt(0);
               sw[v + 1] = st.charAt(1);
               c = 1;
               st = "";
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: .....and what is your question? What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Please provide the code that you tried as well

Comment: `System.out.println("aaaaaggff".length())`

Comment: You need to edit your question and tell us what the problem is.  Show the code you’ve written—in your question, not in comments.  You’ve told us what output you expect;  you also need to tell us what output you’re getting instead.

Comment: I tried and tried but couldn't able to get excat logic

Comment: I edited your code.  Please add the variables with the appropriate dimensions and remove your comment with the code.

Comment: By "Output (not successfull)" do you mean "required output, but the code doesn't return this"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption here is that you want to print the number a character repeats before it changes.

You can try:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String input = "aaaaaggff";
      char c = input.charAt(0);
      int count = 1;

      System.out.print(c);
      for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++) {
          if (input.charAt(i) == c) {
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i));
            count++;    
          } else {
            System.out.print(count);
            System.out.print(input.charAt(i));  

            count = 1;
            c = input.charAt(i);
          }
      }
      // Print the count of the final character
      System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
aaaaa5gg2ff2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have saved my time.

Comment: @MADHUkandukuri If this answers your question, then kindly check it so it’s marked answered.

Comment: Yes, I checked it's working fine.

Comment: @MADHUkandukuri There’s a check mark next to my answer. You click that.